# How to unlock an sqlite3 db?

Tags: python, django

OMG!

What an apparent problem... my django based scripts have locked my sqlite db...

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: What do you mean "locked"? Can you paste an exception or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your database is locked because you have a transaction running somewhere.

Stop all your Django apps.  If necessary, reboot.

It's also remotely possible that you crashed a SQLite client in the middle of a transaction and the file lock was left in place.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the database file isn't read-only or that you don't have database already open by other application. E.g.

```
$ ps aux | grep sqlite
martin   21118  0.0  0.3


$ kill -9 21118
```

Comment: This is a good general solution if you're not worried about outstanding transactions.